# how to create string resource manager system in web application by jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am in beginning of a web project and I want to read my web site stings such as labels, title of pages, placeholder and ... from a json file. i think this approach may help me to increase my speed in changes and create a multi language web site. 
is there any jquery library for doing this? and if ther is not how can i do this work by jquery?

Comment: no server-side rendering?

Comment: exactly..... in client side only :) i know how to solve this in angular but i don't want use angular in this project

Comment: I'd say you'd need templates like in https://lodash.com/docs#template - not jQuery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're searching for is a Javascript/jQuery Template Engine - there are lot of them (start e.g. with http://www.sitepoint.com/10-javascript-jquery-templates-engines/ ).

If you want to write your own template engine try the following:

1) Fetch JSON-Data with Ajax

2) Fetch Template with Ajax

3) Apply variables from JSON-File to Template File (simple replace)

4) Append the result to the current page.

Comment: i donot search for "Javascript/jQuery Template Engine" i was not aware of this. thank you for this reminding.

Answer (score 3):

You can make mustache templates and populate them with data using handlebars.js:
http://handlebarsjs.com/

Mustache templates use curly braces as placeholders and handlebars uses the json format to hold the data. It could look something like this (though not a full working example):

HTML:

```
<div class="entry">
  <h1>{{title}}</h1>
  <div class="body">
    {{body}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
var context = {title: "My New Post", body: "This is my first post!"};
var html    = template(context);
```

Result:

```
<div class="entry">
  <h1>My New Post</h1>
  <div class="body">
    This is my first post!
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is a working example: https://jsfiddle.net/k4u64exL/